# Visually reformatting table rows only via CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to convert a table's design to be conveniently viewable on mobile devices. The table may contain many rows with cells containing longer text as well as numbers and other short data, so it's way too wide to fit on a mobile screen in its original form. I found some approaches for making tables responsive (i.e.: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/), but they all rely on reformatting the table rows to essentially become a list. In my case this would be a huge waste of screen space and it would force the user to scroll a lot. So I came up with the idea of visually expanding one table row into two or more rows in a way that cells with more content get a single row on their own and cells with less content may share one row with each other.

For example, a table row like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>20%</td>
    <td>5002</td>
    <td class="longText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
      </ul>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Some Link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
```

Should visually become this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>20%</td>
    <td>5002</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
      </ul>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Some Link</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="longText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
```

A workaround would be to add the second row in HTML and hide / show it and the other "longText"-table cell via CSS according to the viewer's screen size, but this isn't the best solution for obvious reasons. I'd like to achieve my second markup example only via CSS if possible, but so far I didn't find any solution. Is there any way to do this or is it just impossible?

Comment: Maybe **[this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)** is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

To add an additional table row means changing the DOM at specific widths:

```
(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
       //remove your table row
    }
    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
       //add your table row
    }
});
```

However I don't think that is practical for your purposes, it will be much harder to manage and would become convoluted. Personally I would use media queries in your stylesheet to hide the row's content:

```
 <td class="longText hideme"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</p></td>

 @media (max-width: 991px) { .hideme p {display:none} }
```

Here is a [bit of reading](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) from CSS Tricks